toggle button status is not changing
{
      dataField: activationStates.active,
      text: "Active",
      formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
        const toggleId = `active-status-toggle-${rowIndex + 1}`;
        return (
          <label className="toggle-switch">
            <Switch
              checked={row.active}
              id={toggleId}
              onChange={() => handleUserActivation(row)}
              style={{
                color: row.active ? globalColor.muiBlue : "#fff",
              }}
              classes={{
                switchBase: row.active ? "Mui-checked" : "",
                track: row.active ? "active-track" : "inactive-track",
              }}
            />
          </label>
        );
      },
      headerClasses: "active-status",
      headerAttrs: { id: "header-active" },
      filter: tableFilter
        ? selectFilter({
            className: "custom-text-filter",
            options: selectOptions,
            defaultValue: "unknown",
          })
        : null,
    }

this is my code here I mean in the UI when I click on the toggle button it is fetching the API but it the status of the toggle button state is not changing
I trying by making some changes in my code but it is not working I even go throgh the gpt but still no use
What I was expecting is that when I clcik on toggle to should fetch the API and chane it's state like if it was in active state then it should change to inactive state
